# when using jade I'm gettin Error: "Failed to lookup view"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am net to coding node.js program.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('/index/:name',function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And here is my index.jade

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title= title
```

When i run call localhost:8080/index/example from web browser, I get error that is below:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index.jade"
    at Function.render (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:489:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:716:7)
    at /home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/app.js:9:6
    at callbacks (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:37)
    at param (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:134:11)
    at param (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:131:11)
    at pass (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:141:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:169:4)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:32:10)
    at next (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

What is the problem? And how can i solve?

Comment: looks like express cannot find the index.jade file. Do you have a file called index.jade in your views folder?

Comment: It's in the same folder, It haven't got views folder. Need i to create views folder? @zeMirco

Comment: do you still get the error when you put the view inside the views folder? or try to add some config `app.set('views', __dirname);` Then you should not need the extra folder.

Comment: @zeMirco bingo! ok, can i define two different folder for view files?

Comment: No you can't (there is only one root directory). But (all subdirectories are included)

Comment: You need to create views folder at your root directory. Make sure that you have install jade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your views folder

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set("view engine", "jade");
    app.set("views", __dirname + "/public");
});
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: it says `configure` is not a function

Comment: Added a second solution.